# Apple certificates with two teams

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I've been developing iOS apps using certificates, push certificates and profiles. Using the same certSigningRequest I got my public key, my private key, my developer and production certificates and my developer and production APNS certificates.

My problems began when I was invited to a company's team. I requested a new developer certificate, a new production certificate, a new developer APNS certificate and a new production APNS certificate using my certSigningRequest. It seems that everything worked well because all these certificates are shown in my keychain and all are valid.

But there are a couple of things that are confusing me:

- In Keychain:Certificates my new developer certificate is attached to a new private key. My private key is called "iOS Developer: my name" and my new private key is called "iOS Developer: my name (my company name>)". Is this normal?
- In keychain:keys there are a new private key (the one I've commented before) and a new public key called as the private key "iOS Developer: my name (my company name)". Why has been created a new pair public/private keys if I used the same certSigningRequest?
- Finally, Production Push notifications for my company are not working (Developer Push notifications are working properly).

I've generated Developer PN pem file using my new developer push notification certificate & my new private key(the one associated to that certificate) >> working.

I've generated Production PN pem file using my new production push notification certificate & my private key (the one associated to that certificate) >> not working.

Since the process is the same is there a problem with the certificates?

Comment: I think it is a good idea to post this question on eveloper.apple.com. It sometimes helps to revoke and delete existing profiles and certificates and create new ones. If that's the case in your situation... no idea. I self encountered problems with profiles and certificates and deleteing the old and creating new ones solved my problems.

Comment: Hello A3O. Thank you for your answer! I posted this question on developer.apple.com, but I didn't receive any answer, so I tried here. I thought on your suggestion of revoke all certificates and request them again, but since my certificates are ok I'm a bit afraid to break it all.